# How do I now which DLLs are part of C++?

Tags: c++, deployment, dependencies

I've opened up my program in Dependency Walker. It shows the following DLLs:

- GDI32.DLL
- OLEAUT32.DLL
- IMM32.DLL
- WINMM.DLL
- KERNEL32.DLL
- USER32.DLL
- SHELL32.DLL
- OLE32.DLL
- ADVAPI32.DLL
- WS2_32.DLL
- MSVCP100.DLL
- MSVCR100.DLL

So I'm guessing half of those are part of Windows and the other half is part of C++, right? What is the best method to find out which are part of the OS and which aren't?

Comment: I doubt there really is an answer here -- a DLL is just a collection of functions. It's entirely up to us, after the fact, to classify some of those as Part of X vs. part of Y.

Comment: So I'm out of luck? I'm trying to package the required DLLs into the one folder. I can't use an installer because the target machine requires that installers are not used. I can't use the -MT flag because it uses the Qt libraries.

Comment: That is what I'm using to get the list of DLLs. That is Dependency Walker.

Comment: Microsoft includes a list of redistributables. That's you're guide to what you can/can't include with your application. For most things, vc_redist.exe is the main thing to include.

Comment: If you persist in this no installers stance, updates to Windows DLLs have a decent chance of breaking your install.  The installer database(s) help keep track of what app relies on what DLL and with no info about your app things could easily break.  Look into the side-by-side DLL concept...

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "Windows DLLs have a decent chance of breaking your install." If I'm not using an installer, then there is no install to begin with, right?

Comment: @user87504: You don't need an automatic installer to have an _installation_. In your case, your installation is simply a manually-emplaced executable. The installer is the _user_ (or a `.zip` extraction operation).

Comment: Look at what directory a DLL is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVCP100.dll and MSVCR100.dll contain the runtime libraries for C and C++. Everything else in the list belongs to windows. One way to determine if a DLL belongs to windows is to look at it's path (c:\windows...) and then check for a digital signature from MS. It's not foolproof but it'll get you a bit closer to determining if the DLL belongs to windows or not.

Edit: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855370/845568) answer by Lightness Races In Orbit concerning distributing Windows DLL's

Comment: Brilliant! I ended up using "Search Everything" (google it) to search for each DLL on my hard drive. If the DLL is only located in the SysWOW64/System32/WinSxS folders, then it comes with Windows.

Comment: @user87504: It is absolutely not true that you should ship any DLL not found in those folders. _Please do not do this._ When I accidentally install anything written by you, you may be mangling the dependencies on my computer (and purely out of ignorance, at that).

Comment: Lightness is right. I didn't realize your intention was to package up Windows DLL's for distribution.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't package up *any* DLLs that you didn't explicitly add into the project yourself.**

Read the documentation for your toolchain (Visual Studio, or whatever) to find out if there are any *redistributables* that you need to include in your package. Those may include some DLLs.

If you are not allowed to publish an *installer* (the form of which is generally taken by said redistributables for Microsoft products), then you shall not simply manually dump DLLs instead. You shall remark in your *release notes* that those dependencies must already be installed on the target system. You make them a *pre-requisite* for your application.

Comment: How are you going to install redistributable without an installer: "I can't use an installer because the target machine requires that installers are not used."

Comment: @Lol4t0: Please point me to the place where I said we shall not use installers.

Comment: See my citation from the @user87504's comment to the question.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Ah, I see. Well, I reject that premise. If an installer is not allowed, then randomly dumping system DLLs is not allowed, either. The OP should instead seek to either: (a) get permission to use installers, (b) simply note in his app's release notes that "redistributables for VS 2008 [or whatever] are a pre-requisite, and must be available on the system". Job done.

Comment: Hmm I went to the VS2010 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd831853%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but I can't find anything on redistributables. According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, a redistributable is software update package. What do you mean if I need to include any redistributables?

Comment: @user87504: Precisely that.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Is randomly dumping system DLLs not allowed even if it stays in the same directory as my binary (the directory will be named foo on the destop)?

Comment: @user87504: It's messy and horrible. Sure, you may avoid causing irreparable harm. However, you won't get any money from me for a license for your next software version!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What if I drop the DLLs when the program starts and erase them when the program ends?

Comment: @user87504: That's even worse! Sneaky

Answer (score 0):

Other than looking them up using Google, there's probably no easy way to tell. However, in this case I can tell you that `MSVCP100.DLL` is the C++ standard library code, and `MSVCR100.DLL` is the C runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Walker itself has list of 'known system DLLs'. You can find it in Options -> Configure Module Search Order menu.